# ¿Qué forma verbal se prefiere a la hora de preguntar y contestar?

Tags: discusión

Acostumbrado como estoy a preguntar en Stack Overflow en inglés, no me había dado cuenta que en castellano hay más conjugaciones y, por ende, resulta algo más complicado saber qué registro y forma verbal conviene utilizar a la hora de preguntar.

Es por eso que me pregunto: ¿cuál de las siguientes formas de preguntar es más recomendable?

- ¿Cómo puedo hacer X? (1ª persona sing)
- ¿Cómo puede hacerse X? (impersonal)
- ¿Cómo podemos hacer X? (1ª persona plural)

Y a la hora de contestar, ¿cuál conviene utilizar?

- Puedes hacer Y (2ª persona sing)
- Lo que se puede hacer es Y (impersonal)
- Podemos hacer Y (1ª persona plural)
- Y sus correspondientes versiones en condicional: *podrías hacer Y*, etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mi opinion es que no importa mucho.  De verdad, hay varias formas en inglés, también, y usamos todos en SO en inglés:

- [How can I...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-using-jquery?s=1|18.5497) / ¿Cómo puedo...?
- [How do I...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260748/how-do-i-remove-a-git-submodule?s=1|10.2102) / ¿Cómo hago...?
- [How does one...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55828/how-does-one-parse-xml-files?s=1|2.1827) / ¿Cómo puede hacerse...?
- [How do we...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372317/how-do-we-count-rows-using-hibernate?s=2|2.0603) / ¿Cómo podemos...?
- [How can you...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/316265/how-can-you-speed-up-eclipse?s=1|7.2123) / ¿Cómo puedes...?
- [Can you...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/351733/can-you-write-object-oriented-code-in-c?s=7|2.8684) / ¿Puedes...?
- [Is it possible...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23569441/is-it-possible-to-apply-css-to-half-of-a-character?s=1|4.7307) / ¿Es posible...?
  Etc, etc...

Todos son válidos, correctos, y comunes (a varias grados).

En resumen, no es una problema, entonces no tenemos que hacer nada.

Comment: Exactamente, lo que importa es que la pregunta o respuesta sea útil y que se pueda leer.

Answer (score 0):

Para preguntas, creo que debe usarse la primera persona o la forma impersonal... prefiero la conjugación en primera persona (a fin de cuentas, soy *yo* quien hace la pregunta), pero si la pregunta está formulada *claramente* en forma impersonal, no veo ningún inconveniente. Respecto del uso de la primera persona en plural, en lo personal no me siento cómodo (no le veo el caso al "mayestático")

Para respuestas, creo que lo correcto es seguir el patrón establecido en la pregunta: Una pregunta hecha en primera persona puede responderse en segunda persona, y una pregunta hecha de forma impersonal puede responderse de forma impersonal (mi opinión del plural se mantiene).

Ahora bien, ante todo debe preponderarse la **claridad** de la pregunta o de la respuesta. Sin importar la conjugación o el estilo de escritura (o las variaciones del idioma), toda publicación debe ser clara.

Mi pequeña recomendación final sería:

> Es mejor ***rápido, preciso y conciso*** 
> que ***lento, difuso y confuso***.

Answer (score 0):

Lo habitual es que una pregunta de Stack Overflow plantee una problema que tiene la persona que la ha redactado, y que las respuestas estén dirigidas "directamente" a esa persona. Así que en mi opinión, lo más normal sería que las preguntas estuvieran planteadas como *"¿Cómo puedo/podría...?"* y las respuestas como *"Puedes/podrías"*... (aunque *"¿Es posible...?"* es una buena alternativa).

No obstante, como dice Flimzy tampoco es que este punto tenga gran importancia; lo principal es que las preguntas y las respuestas estén bien redactadas y sean útiles para quien pregunta y para todo aquel que encuentra las respuestas a posteriori.